# WPF DataGridComboBoxColumn loses value after focus is lost

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridcomboboxcolumn

after trying a lot of (not working) solutions, I hope someone can help me.

If the focus of the selected row in my DataGrid is lost, the selected value of the ComboBox column will also be lost.

This is my XAML-Code

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridComboBoxTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridComboBoxTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="dataGrid"></DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

And her is the CS Code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace DataGridComboBoxTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Some Sample Data

            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Name");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Age");

            DataRow dataRow1 = dataTable.NewRow();
            dataRow1["Name"] = "John";
            dataRow1["Age"] = "33";
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow1);

            DataRow dataRow2 = dataTable.NewRow();
            dataRow2["Name"] = "Emily";
            dataRow2["Age"] = "19";
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow2);

            this.dataGrid.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;

            //Add ComboBox Column
            Dictionary<string, string> genders = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            genders.Add("f", "female");
            genders.Add("m", "male");

            DataGridComboBoxColumn dgCmbColumn = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
            dgCmbColumn.Header = "Gender";

            dgCmbColumn.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
            dgCmbColumn.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
            dgCmbColumn.ItemsSource = genders;


            this.dataGrid.Columns.Add(dgCmbColumn);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried a lot of solutions with Bindings, but nothing works for me.

Comment: Binding is far quicker and easier, consider using a VM instead of code-behind, then create and use a property 'SelectedGender' in your VM as the 'SelectedItemBinding' in the DatagridComboboxColumn.

Answer (score 1):

> If the focus of the selected row in my `DataGrid` is lost, the selected value of the `ComboBox` column will also be lost.

That's because you don't store the currently selected value somewhere.

Add a column to your `DataTable`:

```
dataTable.Columns.Add("Gender");
```

...and set the `SelectedValueBinding` property of the column:

```
dgCmbColumn.SelectedValueBinding = new Binding("Gender");
```

Comment: But if I scroll down so far that the items getting invisible and scroll up again, the Values will be lost again. I guess that the binding is not working properly.

Comment: @ToM_ToM: If you debug your code and look at the current value of the `ItemsSource`, does it contain any "Gender" column and values?

Comment: Yes It contains a Gender column, but without any values.

Comment: @ToM_ToM: And the `ItemsSource` of the `ComboBox` is still a `Dictionary<string, string>`?

Comment: Yes, It is.
`DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add("Name");
dataTable.Columns.Add("Age");
dataTable.Columns.Add("Gender");`

`Dictionary<string, string> genders = new Dictionary<string, string>();
genders.Add("f", "female");
genders.Add("m", "male");`

Comment: @ToM_ToM: Could you please edit your question with what you currently have then?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest defining your columns in XAML as it is more readable than in code-behind:

```xml
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Age}"/>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Gender" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Gender}" x:Name="myComboBoxColumn"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In your code-behind, do not forget to also define a data column for the gender:

```cs
dataTable.Columns.Add("Gender");
```

For easy manipulation of gender, let's create an `enum`:

```cs
public enum Gender { Male, Female, Other }
```

And finally, set the `ItemsSource` of your column to your list of genders:

```cs
myComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource = new Gender[] { Gender.Male, Gender.Female, Gender.Other };
```

---

Total code-behind becomes:

```cs
InitializeComponent();

//Some Sample Data

DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add("Name");
dataTable.Columns.Add("Age");
dataTable.Columns.Add("Gender");

DataRow dataRow1 = dataTable.NewRow();
dataRow1["Name"] = "John";
dataRow1["Age"] = "33";
dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow1);

DataRow dataRow2 = dataTable.NewRow();
dataRow2["Name"] = "Emily";
dataRow2["Age"] = "19";
dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow2);

this.dataGrid.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
myComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource = new Gender[] { Gender.Male, Gender.Female, Gender.Other };
```